# invoke() method on cypress doesn't work if called twice

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress, invoke

I'm new with Cypress and I'm trying to implement some easy tests using an already existing webpage. I'm a little bit confused about the result, because I call invoke() twice: the first time to check the initial value (0%), and the second one to set a new value and check the change, but it doesn't work, and it tells me that it cannot find the attribute I'm searching for. The code is the following:

```
describe('My first test', function(){
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit("https://www.wikiwand.com/en/IPv4")
    })
    it('test1', function() {
        const opt = cy.get("#main_menu > li").eq(3).click()
        const sty = opt.get(".noUi-origin").first()
        sty.invoke("attr", "style").should("include", "left: 0%;")
        sty.invoke("attr", "style", "left: 100%;").should("have.attr", "style", "left: 100%;")
         
        
    })
})
```

I simply take the personalize button on the menu bar, and I want to change the value serif or sans. There is a problem with the order of the two invoke()? The error is:

```
*Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.invoke() errored because the property: attr does not exist on your subject.
cy.invoke() waited for the specified property attr to exist, but it never did.
If you do not expect the property attr to exist, then add an assertion such as:
cy.wrap({ foo: 'bar' }).its('quux').should('not.exist')*
```

on

```
sty.invoke("attr", "style", "left: 100%;").should("have.attr", "style", "left: 100%;")
```

Has someone an idea about it?

Comment: So your element has both `left: 0%;` and `left: 100%;` mentioned under style attribute ? Would be great if you could share the entire html of the element.

Comment: @AlapanDas it is the webpage on wikipedia https://www.wikiwand.com/en/IPv4, you can see the html there with inspect. The left is in the html under style attribute, yes.

Comment: Yes I figured out that later. I have answered your question, you can check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypress commands run in a "chain", with the current "subject" being passed from one command to the next.

Although you think you are saving a reference to the element in `const sty = ...`, actually you are saving a pointer to the internal Cypress subject.

When you do `sty.invoke("attr", "style")`, you have now changed the subject to that style attribute, not the element.

So when you try to `sty.invoke("attr", "style")` again, `sty` no longer has an `attr` method, hence the error.

More conventional way is not to store command results.

Just re-query

```js
const opt = cy.get("#main_menu > li").eq(3).click()

cy.get(".noUi-origin").first()
  .invoke("attr", "style")
  .should("include", "left: 0%;")

cy.get(".noUi-origin").first()
  .invoke("attr", "style", "left: 100%;")
  .should("have.attr", "style", "left: 100%;")
```

Or use an assertion that does not change the subject

```js
const opt = cy.get("#main_menu > li").eq(3).click()

cy.get(".noUi-origin").first()
  .should("have.css", "left", "0px")       // keeps the same subject
  .invoke("attr", "style", "left: 100%;")
  .should("have.attr", "style", "left: 100%;")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the code is really clear, but I have a small doubt about why attr doesn't exist anymore. I understood that I'm using a pointer, but why attr changes? I mean, I don't change the name of the attribute "style", I'm only checking its value.

Comment: It's not the attribute "style" that changes, it's the Cypress subject. Initially the subject is pointing at the element, but `invoke()` changes the subject to point at the value of the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

So the Font slider when it is **Serif** the style is `left: 0%;` and when you drag the slider to **Sans** the style is `left: 100%;`. So your test should look like this:

```js
cy.visit("https://www.wikiwand.com/en/IPv4");
cy.get("#main_menu > li").eq(3).click();
cy.get(".noUi-origin")
  .first()
  .invoke("attr", "style")
  .should("include", "left: 0%;");
cy.get('[ng-click="$root.fontStyleHandler(1, true)"]').click(); //Drags the slider from Serif to Sans
cy.get(".noUi-origin")
  .first()
  .invoke("attr", "style")
  .should("include", "left: 100%;");
```

Or, if you don't want to use the slider then you have to first remove the style attribute and then add the style attribute with value `left: 100%;`, in that case your test should look like:

```js
cy.visit("https://www.wikiwand.com/en/IPv4")
cy.get("#main_menu > li").eq(3).click()
cy.get(".noUi-origin")
  .first()
  .invoke("attr", "style")
  .should("include", "left: 0%;")
cy.get(".noUi-origin").first().invoke("removeAttr", "style")
cy.get(".noUi-origin").first().invoke("attr", "style", "left: 100%;")
cy.get(".noUi-origin")
  .first()
  .invoke("attr", "style")
  .should("include", "left: 100%;")
```

Comment: thank you. The first 6 lines are clear, but I'm a little bit in trouble with the others: where the 7th line comes from? And why I simply cannot change the value using invoke?